# Spring Data Elastic Search with dynamic document replicas and shards

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using spring boot 2.4 and spring-data-elasticsearch 4.1. I have document like this

```
@Document(indexName = "test", replicas = 3, shards = 2)
public class TestDocument {
  @Id
  @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
  private String Id;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Object, enabled = false)
  private String name;
  ...
  getters
  setters
}
```

And i want to override hardcoded values in replicas and shards in Document annotation from application.yml for index creation because this values can be differnet by environment of my service. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable auto-creation of an index by using

```
@Document(indexName = "test", createIndex = false)
```

and then create the index by using the `IndexOperations.create(settings)`. The following code is taken from Spring Data Elasticsearch tests (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.1.x/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplateTests.java#L2361-L2384):

```java
    public void shouldCreateIndexWithGivenClassAndSettings() {

        // given
        String settings = "{\n" + "        \"index\": {\n" + "            \"number_of_shards\": \"1\",\n"
                + "            \"number_of_replicas\": \"0\",\n" + "            \"analysis\": {\n"
                + "                \"analyzer\": {\n" + "                    \"emailAnalyzer\": {\n"
                + "                        \"type\": \"custom\",\n"
                + "                        \"tokenizer\": \"uax_url_email\"\n" + "                    }\n"
                + "                }\n" + "            }\n" + "        }\n" + '}';

        // when
        indexOperations.delete();
        indexOperations.create(parse(settings));
        indexOperations.putMapping(SampleEntity.class);
        indexOperations.refresh();

        // then
        Map<String, Object> map = indexOperations.getSettings();
        assertThat(operations.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of(INDEX_NAME_SAMPLE_ENTITY)).exists()).isTrue();
        assertThat(map.containsKey("index.number_of_replicas")).isTrue();
        assertThat(map.containsKey("index.number_of_shards")).isTrue();
        assertThat((String) map.get("index.number_of_replicas")).isEqualTo("0");
        assertThat((String) map.get("index.number_of_shards")).isEqualTo("1");
    }
```

Instead of parsing the JSON for the settings you should create a `Document` in your code:

```java
Document settings = Document.create();
settings.put("index.number_of_replicas", 42);
settings.put("index.number_of_shards", 42);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can Add a @Setting annotion to you Entity,  which is provided by spring-data-elasticsearch, in order to help you custom index info .

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearc.misc.index.settings

[image]